# Increase speed on elasticsearch-py scans

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-py

I'm looking for a way to increase the speed of the scroll-scan over my elasticsearch data.
The following python code scans over multiple indices and spews out the findings to console and to a file located somewhere.
My tests concluded that this method of doing it is extremely inefficient and takes enormous amounts of time (10 events / sec?). I guess this is caused by some internal defaults or limits.
Is there a way I can design it to achieve better performance?

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q

client = Elasticsearch(
    [
        'http://localhost:9201/',
    ],
    verify_certs=True
)

search = Search(using=client, index="test1,test2,test3") \
    .filter(Q("wildcard", name="bob*") & Q("term", color="green")) \
    .filter('range', **{'@timestamp':{'gte': 'now-2d', 'lt': 'now'}}) \
    .sort('@timestamp') \
    .params(preserve_order=True)



file = open("X:/files/people.txt", "a")
for hit in search.scan():
    line = (hit.message + "\n")
    file.write(line)
    print(line)

file.close()
```

Thank you for looking into this :)

Answer (score 1):

Old question but might help someone else:

Other two things to try is tweaking `size`, find an optimal value that works for your environment. Also if you don't necessary need full `_source`, try eliminating fields with `_source_exclude` or `_source_include`, I've seen great performance improvements using those.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make it faster is to remove the `sort` and `preserve_order` parameters. You might also look into sliced scroll to run multiple scans in parallel using `multiprocessing`, you can see an example at (0). Hope this helps!

0 - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/817#issuecomment-372271460